# Real Time personalized videos

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I would like to achieve a video with custom text pulled from a database or user input as the following :
http://videopersonalization.net/kia.html

Can somebody shed some light on the process without using a third party please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using a third party"? You mean no third party libraries (outside of standard libraries for whatever platform you're programming on)? That would probably be extremely hard.

Comment: @aldel I meant without paying a third party to use their services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is going to be a very high-level answer (no code), because it's a pretty major undertaking. You'll need to research the details.

First you need to do feature tracking in the original video. That gives you a set of moving points that track objects or parts of objects in the frame. I know that Adobe Premiere Pro includes a way of doing this; I'm assuming that it provides a way to save the coordinates to a format that you can use in your software, although I haven't actually checked. I'm guessing that Final Cut Pro probably has an equivalent feature.

OpenCV (a computer vision library) also can do feature tracking, if you want to do it all programmatically.

For each video, you'll want to manually choose a few points on the surface that you want the text to appear on. Render the text in relation to those points. How to render moving text is a huge topic, and will depend on things like how realistic you want it to appear, and whether you want it to exactly match the lighting conditions of the original video. Hopefully you already know a bit about graphics.

In your server software, then, each time a request comes in for a personalized video, you'll decode the video from whatever format it's in into raw bitmap frames, render the text onto each frame, and then encode it into a delivery format like mp4 or webm. You can do that with ffmpeg, either by piping it through the command-line version of ffmpeg or by using the library in your software. If you want low latency, you might have to stream the video back to the client as it's being rendered. My best guess is that the example you linked to does this, although the videos are short enough that it might be able to encode the whole video into a file, then transmit it.

Or, to save CPU processing on the server, you might be able to send the original video to the web client, plus the coordinates of the tracked points, and use WebGL to render the text in the browser. It might be hard to keep it perfectly synchronized.